# How do I make an application accessible to all users in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, atom-editor

I've installed the [Atom.io](http://Atom.io) editor as myself but also want it to be usable by my daughter under her account. It is under `C:/Users/Bruno/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.3.2/atom.exe` I don't want to reinstall multiple copies of every app for every users. That is insanity. I've searched for answers but all the Windows 2000, 7, and 8 methods do not apply. I haven't tried to use Windows since 98. Now I remember why.

Comment: If you reinstall the program one time, the install should ask you, "Install for current user, or for, all users on this computer". If not then proceed to read. I've never used Atom but if it's Windows you should be able to press the Windows icon to open programs, then right click on "All Programs". Open two folders: Win icon then, Right click on All Programs and choose Open. That's one folder. Then Right Click on All Programs again and choose Open All Users. You can navigate to the program in the first folder, Cut the folder and paste it into the folder All Users. Now its' shared to all users.

Comment: My comment above regarding "cut the folder": The folders in the start menu are just folders with shortcuts. Each user has their own menu. But there is also an All Users folder. So cutting the folder from your user account and pasting it in the All Users folder does not move the program, it only moves the shortcuts in the menu to appear to any user. Windows will make available to the users whom have access to this folder; it's a shared folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think the path you gave is the path to the shortcut created in your profile to Atom.io. The real install location must be different. You can find the real install location by right clicking the Atom.io shortcut-> Properties -> Open File Location.

If it is installed in C:\ or C:\Program Files,then you can login into your daughter's account and navigate to Atom.io's install location. Then by right clicking Atom.io's main executable, select Send to -> Desktop (Create a shortcut)

Comment: You are right. That is the path to just a link. I've updated the question with the correct path which her user still cannot see.

Comment: Try uinstalling it, run the installer as Run as administrator and see if gives you the ability to install in Program Files

Comment: Interesting. Can I just move it to `Program Files` without breaking the world? I moved it (and got the administrator prompt) and my shortcuts lost their icons and some of them broken. I fixed those but wonder if there are other consequences.

Comment: I downloaded Atom.io. It does not give an installer. But if you use 7zip, you can extract the contents of the setup into a folder. It uses Squirel (Update.exe) and passes a command "Update.exe --install ." We can change that to Update.exe" --install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atom\" and see if it installs correctly

Comment: I ran the installer as Administrator and it recreated the copy at `C:/Users/Bruno/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.3.2/atom.exe`

Comment: I tired the commandline. Squrriel installs it in AppData no matter what you do.

Comment: see https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows

Comment: Thanks @ganesh-r. Squirriel looks really cool. The [installation points](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows#installation) sound really promising. Of course it is from GitHub. Clearly they know how to do Windows right. I wonder why they didn't give an "Install for all users" checkbox.

Comment: My understanding is to avoid UAC and because it is meant for packages and packages are normally per user. MAy be you can request for the feature in squirrel.